# Reduce float precision using RegExp in swift

Tags: swift, regex

I'm trying to reduce the precision of the floats that are embedded in a strings.

`The example is [93829.38, 1415.45467897]`

I'd like to cut float numbers obtaining float number with a maximum precision of 2 (I can cut the string directly, no needs to round the numbers somehow).

`The example is [93829.38, 1415.45]`

with this regexp on rubular I can get float numbers in the string:
`(\d+\.\d)`

But I can't understand how to port this regexp on Swift and how to substitute the float strings with the shortest ones...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
let str = "The example is [93829.38, 1415.45467897, 1.2, 134.34]"
let pattern = "(\\d+\\.\\d{2})\\d+"
let result = str.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "$1", options: [.regularExpression])
print(result) // => The example is [93829.38, 1415.45, 1.2, 134.34]
```

A pattern like `(\d+\.\d{2})\d+` will match and capture into Group 1 one or more diigts, a dot and then two digits, and then will match one or more digits. The replacement is `$1`, the backreference to the value stored in Group 1, thus, truncating the digits matched with the last `\d+`.

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/yINM4e/1).

If there are any edge cases, they can usually be handled by means of word boundaries (`\b`) or lookarounds.

Comment: this regex `(\d+\.\d{,2})\d*` have a better selection for precision under 2 digits

Comment: @Erwan `(\d+\.\d{0,2})\d*` will match `12.`, `12.1`, `12.12` and since these strings should not be modified, there is no need matching them at all.